# FFPLAY unable to facebook live stream url i.e. rtmps url

Tags: ffmpeg, facebook-live-api, rtmps

I am trying to play facebook live **streraming url** using ffplay where **i have used rtmps stream url & stream key**. I have enabled **openssl** library and rtmps library in ffmpeg. But while running command of ffplay with stream url & key, i am getting ***Pull function error***.
So is there any solution known please let me know.
**Thank you.**

Comment: Hi @Shankar, could you please tell me how you are getting the stream URL and key from Facebook??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a valid method of playing back the video. Facebook disables RTMP pull, they only use RTMPs for push, i.e. sending video TO Facebook, not getting video FROM Facebook. There is nothing you can do to make that work.

Comment: Thank you for response sir. But as we all know RTMPS uses secure line for live streaming. So there must be any way from that we can enable RTMPS Pull so that we can ffplay live streaming video. As i am live broadcasting from my facebook account only, and i want to ffplay that live streaming video. So please reply if you know anything about that. Thank you.

Comment: RTMPS is just RTMP over TLS. but that’s totally irrelevant to your question. When you send a stream to an RTMP (or RTMPS) endpoint, you connect, then send a publish command, the server then accepts a media stream. When you attempt to play a stream, the client sends a play command, and the server then starts sending media to the client. Facebook modified the server logic. When the client sends a play command, instead of returning the media, the server just disconnects you.

Comment: There is absolutely 100% no way to play RTMP from facebook. The facebook servers convert the RTMP stream to HLS or DASH to playback on the site/apps.

Comment: @szatmary can you please let me know hot to send video using rtms, i create the rtms fb url after calling /page_id/live_vides , i want to stream from my admin panel to facebook page